# How to Watch Object Property within a Vue Plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch

## Background

Consider the following, very basic, plugin:

```
import SomeObject from "./SomeObject";

/**
 * Some Cool Plugin...
 */
export default {
    install(Vue){

        Vue.prototype.$someObject = Vue.observable(SomeObject);

    }
}
```

The purpose of the above is to register an object to be reactive throughout my application.

## The Problem & Question

`Vue.prototype.$someObject` contains certain properties that need to be `watched`, on a global level, not a component level.

Is there a way to attach a watcher to the Vue instance within the `install` method of a Vue plugin?

Please note, I am **not** looking for the following answer, I am already aware this can be done but it defeats the point of separating the code into a plugin. A global mixin would also not be sufficient...

```
watch: {

    '$someObject.foo': {
        handler(value) {
            console.log(value);
        }
    }

}
```

## What I have Tried

Based on the documentation outlined [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch), I assumed I could do something along the lines of the following:

```
export default {
    install(Vue){

        Vue.prototype.$someObject = Vue.observable(SomeObject);

        // I have tried all of the following:
        Vue.watch(Vue.prototype.$someObject.foo, value => { console.log(value) });
        Vue.$watch(Vue.prototype.$someObject.foo, value => { console.log(value) });
        Vue.prototype.watch(Vue.prototype.$someObject.foo, value => { console.log(value) });
        Vue.prototype.$watch(Vue.prototype.$someObject.foo, value => { console.log(value) });

        Vue.watch(Vue.$someObject.foo, value => { console.log(value) });
        Vue.$watch(Vue.$someObject.foo, value => { console.log(value) });
        Vue.prototype.watch(Vue.$someObject.foo, value => { console.log(value) });
        Vue.prototype.$watch(Vue.$someObject.foo, value => { console.log(value) });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Vue 2 only Vue instances expose `watch`. When Vue 3 arrives you'll have other options but for now you're stuck with using a Vue instance.

That said, you can have an instance within the plugin, so it should be easy enough to achieve what you want:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import SomeObject from './SomeObject';

/**
 * Some Cool Plugin...
 */
export default {
    install (Vue) {
        Vue.prototype.$someObject = Vue.observable(SomeObject);

        new Vue({
          watch: {
            '$someObject.foo' () {
              // Do something
            }
          }
        })
    }
}
```

The Vue instance created here is not being rendered. It exists purely to give us a way to watch `$someObject`.

I know you ruled this out in the question but I don't really understand why. Perhaps you weren't envisaging creating a dedicated Vue instance specially for the purposes of watching?

An alternative would be to use property setters instead of `watch`. The idea there would be to use `Object.defineProperty` to create a setter for the properties you want to 'watch' and then put whatever side-effects you need within the setter.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I actually thought about creating a separate Vue instance, but I wasn't sure if the new Vue instance would be able to listen to an observable defined on another Vue instance... The reason I wanted to avoid the `watch` property on the Vue instance was simply because I didn't want to define it on my components, but on a separate Vue instance it is absolutely fine, if it works of course. I'll play around now and will come back and accept if I am able to get it to work :-D

Comment: The major caveat to this answer is that every single instance of vue now has the $someObject, not just the instance you created. This is bad practice because it saturates/pollutes the vue objects global space.

Comment: @Hybridwebdev The design decision to make `$someObject` accessible through every Vue instance was part of the original question. In a Vue 2 context it's a commonly used pattern, though it does need to be used sparingly for the reason you mentioned. In the upcoming Vue 3 this pattern has been replaced with less invasive alternatives.